# Can I please have the bounty back?

Tags: support, bounty

[Installing Comodo software on an Apache-based Modsecurity module](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100072/installing-comodo-software-on-an-apache-based-modsecurity-module)

No one answered in a week and most likely there won't be an answer.

Comment: Comodo offers SSL services and software. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Their rule set software which is being updated with each sudo apt-get update is what's needed. What I ask for is a short, didactic explanation of installing it after bumping into 3 different articles which I grasped as undidactic, at the time.

Answer (score 5):

From: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>
> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, no
>   bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.
>
> Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher
>   question visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does
>   not guarantee a response and **is not refunded** if none are received.

Comment: From the same source: "Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher question visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does not guarantee a response and is **not refunded** if none are received."

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Ooopppsss!! I stand corrected! This is what happens when you rush. Cheers!!